# How to fix php in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, php

Once I've upgraded to Yosemite my PHP stopped working. After a quick search I've found [this guide](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/) which worked fine on my work computer.

When I tried the same on my home Mac, it didn't work. 1) on my home Mac I had [entropy](http://php-osx.liip.ch) PHP initially installed, so I followed they guide to uninstall and install a newer version but that didn't work.

I've also tried with standard PHP that came out of the box and that didn't work either.

To clarify: I've cleaned install Yosemite then I imported my user and settings. I've uncommented this line on `httpd.conf`

`LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so` as well as these two:

```
LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
```

I don't want to use the user's Site (i.e.: localhost/~user/myphpapp) and would rather use (localhost/myphpapp) but I did followed the instructions to set users' Site and that didn't work either. (I then reverted back)

To clarify what it means it doesn't work: when I go to `localhost/php/info.php` (where info.php has phpinfo() in it) I can the string `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` but it doesn't execute. When I navigate through my apps, the files are visible, which tells me apache is working fine, just PHP isn't executing the files.

Another point is that php itself is installed. executing `php --version` on terminal gives me the following:

```
PHP 5.6.2 (cli) (built: Oct 21 2014 21:47:13)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

and `which php`

```
/usr/local/php5/bin/php
```

my httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so
```

which is what entropy gave me after installing its script. I can see the libphp5.so in the above directory (its actually a symlink but thats fine I guess)

When I execute `sudo apachectl -t` I get a `Syntax OK` and yes, I did restart apache after my last round of changes. Have even restarted the computer to be sure.

Lastly, when I execute `php app/console server:run` from a symfony app, it does work as expected, PHP is definitely in and working fine.

My only guess is the my `httpd.conf` is broken somehow but I don't know how to fix.

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Mny thanks

Comment: I just ran into this issue when I installed Yosemite recently. Have you since resolved it? Many thanks - Grant

Comment: The problem was indeed in the .httpd.cnf file. Once I've reverted it to the original (there is a original file created) all got back to normal